# Is there a way to create a train dataset for multiple pytorch files in a folder?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a folder with the name `processed_data`.
In this file I have multiple `.pt` files which are named `data_0.pt`, `data_1.pt`, `data_2.pt`, `data_3.pt`, `data_4.pt`, `data_5.pt`, ....., `data_998.pt`, `data_999.pt`, `data_1000.pt`, `data_1001.pt`.
All these .pt files are representing a graph which was created using pytorch-geometric.

My question is, how do I save load all these files to create my training dataset so that I can use them in DataLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A torch DataLoader needs a Dataset object. When defining your Dataset class, you need to implement `__init__`, `__len__`, and `__getitem__`.

`__init__` is easy, but also dependent on your exact use case/context. Assuming the simplest possible situation, I'd define init to take in the data folder and a file which contains names of the training set files (one per line). Then, I'd store each file name in a list as a member of the class. So we'd have:

```
def __init__(self, data_folder, data_list_filename):
    self.data_folder = data_folder
    with open(data_list_filename, 'r') as f:
        self.data_file_list = f.read().splitlines()
```

Ok, now we have two things stored in your Dataloader: 1) the data folder and 2) a list of data filenames. That makes `__len__` especially easy:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data_file_list)
```

And lastly, we just need to deal with `__get_item__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    filename = self.data_file_list[idx]
    data, label = extract_data_from_file(filename) # this is arbitrary because I don't know how you need to do this
    return data, label
```

Then put all of this together under a class:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_folder, data_list_filename):
        self.data_folder = data_folder
        self.data_file_list = open(data_list_filename, 'r').read().splitlines()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        filename = self.data_file_list[idx]
        data, label = extract_data_from_file(filename) # idk how you plan to do this
        return data, label
```

Obviously, your exact use will look different. But this should get you started.